Is there way to say 'but doesn't match `any`' in typescript?
I'm writing a utility type for jest, it looks like this:
export type MockedService<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: jest.MaybeMockedDeep<T[K]>;
};

The purpose is take the interface for our services, and return a type equivilent to wrapping jest.mocked<TheFunctionType> around each of them.
This works well, with one wrinkle:

    interface Foo {
      getA: (a: string, b: string) => Promise<{ c: string }>;
      getB: (e: number, f: number) => Promise<{ g: string }>;
    }

    const correctUsageWithDefaultsWithMockedUtil: MockedService<Foo> = {
      // use of jest.mocked means that the mock implementations are typed properly
      // @ts-expect-error - incorrect return value
      getA: jest.mocked<Foo['getA']>(jest.fn()).mockResolvedValue('abc'),

      // correct return value
      getB: jest.mocked<Foo['getB']>(jest.fn()).mockResolvedValue({ g: 'abc' })
    };

    const correctUsageWithDefaults: MockedService<Foo> = {
      getA: jest.fn().mockRejectedValue(new Error('not implemented')),

      // nb. The mock return values are not stricted enforced, if you
      // don't wrap with jest.mocked!
      getB: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('abc')
    };

If we don't wrap our jest.fn() with a jest.mocked<TheTyping> then the typed return is
jest.Mock<any, any, any> which satisfies the constraint and allows the developer to mock the implementations anyway they like.
Is there a way to extend my typing to be 'but not jest.Mock<any, any, any>'?

You can define MockedService in this way:
export type MockedService<T extends object> = {
  [K in (0 extends (1 & T) ? never : keyof T)]: jest.MaybeMockedDeep<T[K]>;
};

The explanation about why it works is contained in this answer

This isn't quite right, but thanks for the pointer.
